# How to validate the password without clicking button?

Tags: android

Having an Activity, inside activity  having fragment  I want to validate password 
I have used TextWatcher to validate the input but when I enter the invalid password it show invalid password  hint message but problem is when i move to the next edit text then error message is gone

But i want to show the error message until the user enter the valid password even though he is on another edittext [screenshot of entered invalid password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb3Z6.png)

Here is the Textwatcher code

```
       mnewPassword.getInputField().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().length() > 0) {
                    if (!CommonUtils.isPasswordValid(mnewPassword.getText().toString())) {
                        mnewPassword.setUpperHintColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
                        mnewPassword.setHintMessage(getString(R.string.invalidpassword));
                    }else{
                        mnewPassword.setUpperHintColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
                        mnewPassword.setHintMessage(getString(R.string.invalidpassword));
                    }

                } else {
                    mnewPassword.setUpperHintColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
                    mnewPassword.setHintMessage(getString(R.string.invalidpassword));
                    mnewPassword.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    /*if (editable.length() > 0)
                    {
                        if(!CommonUtils.isPasswordValid(mnewPassword.getText().toString()))
                        {
                            mnewPassword.setUpperHintColor(Color.parseColor("#EE3437"));
                            mnewPassword.setHintMessage(getString(R.string.invalidpassword));
                        }
                    }
*/
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do it in `afterTextChanged()` it will be better if you will use `setError()` on focus change not on text change

Comment: but i don't want to use set error , i want show hint message on tip of the Edittext

Comment: That was just a suggestion . Error message is gone because of focus change . Check the code of `EditText` you are using  .

Answer (score 0):

You can set other views(widgets) to view.setFocusable(false) until it validates the password.
Once the password is validated then you can set all the views(widgets) to view.setFocusable(true).
Hope this may help you.